# Spring data cloud flow application properties not working

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

i am trying to use latest 2.10.0 snapshot version with spring boot 3 and i could not get the option to edit the application properties to change my data source url

please see my dashboard screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAzwD.png)

I have added my jar from local machine.

I need to get the edit option for application properties as well

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you are trying to register a custom Spring Boot 3 application with Spring Cloud Dataflow but are unable to edit any application properties. Is that correct?

Please be sure you did the same steps as described in [app registration](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/streams/data-flow-stream/#application-registration).

Are you able to edit the app properties for the built-in applications?

Answer (score 0):

The options to update properties is available when you deploy a stream or task.

The [configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration) options available depend on the platform you are using.